# How to make page to the top when route changes without scrolling in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, scrolltop

Suppose we click on the About Us button, we are directed to a different page, but it doesn’t load from the top. We have to scroll up ourselves to see the content from the beginning. For now my code is working like first directed to a different page and then scroll to top. How can I get directed page to the top without scrolling.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    }
  }, []);

  return (null);
}
export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);




      <BrowserRouter>
      <ScrollToTop />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

React Router's [Scroll Restoration](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration) suggests in the official docs that you create a component that does the exact thing you did, and wrap every page component that you want this behavior on.

The way they suggest you to write that component:

```
export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

another option will be to not send a dependency array to the `useEffect` and it will behave like `componentDidMount`:

```
export default function ScrollToTop() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Would be a better answer if you included a code snippet.

Comment: is this necessary? they have a great code example in the docs I've added

Comment: Answers shouldn't rely on external sources. A quality answer should include all the details and typically quality answers usually see better votes. Another way to look at it is if the link, for whatever reason like an offline server, were to go down, then your answer is meaningless.